# filter datetime in select PDO to show result for NOW

Tags: mysql, datetime, pdo, datetime-format

How can I show results when I filter datetime in PDO to show only the dates for today and not for yesterdar and tomorrow?
I already change the DATE to DATETIME in db because fullcalendar.... so now in the table not show me the dates... how can I change this code to recover the dates for this day:

```
<?
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM CITAS WHERE start = CURDATE() ORDER BY start ASC");
$sql->execute();                                    while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
?>
```

This code working when start was in DATE format but when I change it to DATETIME don't show me nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to think of date range :
­

```
start >= CURDATE() AND start < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

... untested, but you get the idea

Answer (score 1):

Either:

```
WHERE DATE(start) = CURDATE()
```

or:

```
WHERE start >= CURDATE() AND start < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

If there's an index on the `start` column, the second should perform much better.